# ¿Cómo asignarle una plantilla personalizada a una página con una página superior seleccionada?

Tags: php, wordpress

Necesito crear una estructuta de páginas así

Servicios
 -Servicio 1
 -Servicio 2
 -Servicio ...

Pero que cada servicio tenga una plantilla diferente.

Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

A que te refieres con diferentes plantillas, veo que usas wordpress si ya tienes una plantilla lo único que podrías hacer es crear un CSS en el que especifiques por servicio los colores, fondos, etc. y así variarlas.

Answer (score 0):

es muy sencillo.

Si la página es **Servicio1**:

Creas una plantilla de página, page-{slug}.php (por ejemplo page-servicio1.php) con la estructura en html/php/wp-codex que desees.

En esta página tienes que incluir arriba del todo, el código:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Servicio1
*/
?>
```

Automáticamente al editar la página dentro del panel de control de Wordpress te saldra un desplegable tipo este, donde tienes elegir "Servicio1".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Da igual si tiene páginas padres, lo que cuenta es que el elijas bien el template en el desplegable. En todas las páginas que elijas ese template tendran el mismo diseño.

Creo que iban por aquí los tiros, verdad? Si hay algo que no entiendas me lo dices, intentare explicarlo más de forma más extensa si es necesario.